# Convert specific string into int

Tags: string, numbers

I've read in multiple topics about this, but i cant get it.

I have this specific type of string format: 8Y4H20M.
I need to obtain in 3 differents variables

```
Year=8
Hours=4
Minutes=20
```

First i've done this, because the string can have spaces

var cadena = tiempo.ToUpper().Trim();
        //Saco todos los espacios que haya en las cadenas
        cadena = string.Join("", cadena.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

```
    var cont = 0;
    //int dia = 0, hora = 0, minutos = 0;

    string[] numbers = Regex.Split(cadena, @"\D+");
    foreach (string value in numbers)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            if (cont == 0)
            {
                minutos += (Convert.ToInt32(value))*480;
                cont++;
            }
            else if (cont == 1)
            {
                minutos += (Convert.ToInt32(value))*60;
                cont++;
            }
            else if (cont == 2)
            {
                minutos += (Convert.ToInt32(value));
                cont++;
            }


        }
    }
```

But for example. This doesnt work if the string is "8H7M" or if "19Y".I have to search for specific chars and put them in variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a small and easy to understand regex to collect matches details into a dictionary:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<num>[0-9]+)\s*(?<unit>[mhy])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups["unit"].Value, m => m.Groups["num"].Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cnum%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5cs*%28%3f%3cunit%3e%5bmhy%5d%29&i=8Y4H20M%0d%0a8H7M%0d%0a8+h+7+M%0d%0a19+y%0d%0a19Y&o=i). The `(?<num>[0-9]+)\s*(?<unit>[mhy])` matches:

- `(?<num>[0-9]+)` - 1 or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`) and places the result into Group "num"
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `(?<unit>[mhy])` - 1 of 3 letters, in a case insensitive way (due to the flag used): `m`, `h` or `y`, put into Group "unit".

[A simplified code demo](http://ideone.com/OIbo95):

```
string s = "8Y4H20M 8H7M       8 h 7 M      19 y  19Y";
MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<num>[0-9]+)\s*(?<unit>[mhy])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in result) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", m.Groups["unit"].Value, m.Groups["num"].Value);
```

Output:

```
Y / 8
H / 4
M / 20
H / 8
M / 7
h / 8
M / 7
y / 19
Y / 19
```

Comment: it gives me an error Error 3 El tipo 'DevExpress.Office.ISimpleCollection`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that it is not referenced. 'DevExpress.Office.v12.1.Core, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.

Comment: Look for issues outside of this code, it only references `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. The solution I suggest is valid C# code.

Comment: You may try other approaches, I think this one is the most convenient. BTW, does the error mean you are not referencing the LINQ library (`System.Linq`)?

Comment: I dont know, this is the error:  Module 'DevExpress.Office.v12.1.Core, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
should be referenced

this line gives me error
.ToDictionary(x => x.Groups["unit"].Value, m => m.Groups["num"].Value);

Comment: Ok, you actually can live without that - iterate through matches and initialize any class/structure you want to use for storing the results. What do you want to use?

Comment: can  " var ss =new List<string> { "8Y4H20M", "8H7M", "8 h 7 M", "19 y", "19Y" }; "  be replaced to a string variable? it gives me an error that "s" cannot convert element type 'char' to iterator type 'string'.

Comment: In order to use Lists, you need to reference the `System.Collections.Generic` DLL. Did you try referencing the `using`s?

Comment: I mean that my input wont be a list, its gonna be a string, but if a replace the list into a string it gives me an error.

Comment: It does not matter, what you use: a list of values and test them individually or a whole string with multiple matches. See http://ideone.com/OIbo95

Comment: it gives me an error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to type 'DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.Match'.

Srry bothering you

Comment: Use a fully qualified name, [`foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in result)`](http://ideone.com/OIbo95).